# Using repeated measures ANOVA to assess facilities in hotel industry

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have six variables measuring hotels' facilities by a group of managers. In the end, I want to compare mean scores for these six variables to determine which facility is actually favored in the hotel industry.

Can I use a one-way repeated measures ANOVA to check if there are statistical differences between mean scores for these variables?

Comment: For this analysis to make sense, the scales for each of the 6 variables would have to be the same.  (Recall that ANOVA compares means.)  If you used the same scale for each variable, then some form of repeated measures ANOVA may be appropriate.  How many managers and facilities do you have?

Comment: I am using the same 6-points likert scale for the variables. 152 managers, the six variables were actually measuring six different facilities. Each variable consist of minimum 3 - 8 items.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you saying you have 152 managers and each manager rated 6 facilities? If so, what is a variable?  Did each manager rate each of the 6 facilities on several areas?